# apparent permission problem with USB devices

Tags: permissions, virtualbox, usb-device

I've got problems with adding USB devices in `virtualbox` when it's started as user. Starting it as root seems to work fine but when I start it as user, I get:

```
$ VBoxManage list usbhost
Host USB Devices:

<none>
```

Where as root I get:

```
$ sudo VBoxManage list usbhost
Host USB Devices:

UUID:               4483e9b4-ab99-45ff-ad5c-32b8c61971b9
VendorId:           0x058f (058F)
ProductId:          0x6362 (6362)
Revision:           1.0 (0100)
Port:               0
USB version/speed:  2/High
Manufacturer:       Generic
Product:            Mass Storage Device
SerialNumber:       058F63626420
Address:            sysfs:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1//device:/dev/vboxusb/001/003
Current State:      Busy
...
...
```

which results as `<no devices available>` in the virtiualbox UI (when started as user)
I've added my user to the `vboxusers` group (and logged out & rebooted since multiple times):

```
$ groups ron
ron : ron sudo netdev vboxusers wireshark docker
```

I'm not exactly sure how to interpret the below info though:

```
$ id
uid=1001(ron) gid=1001(ron) groups=1001(ron)
```

I'm running the version: `virtualbox-6.0_6.0.0-127566_Ubuntu_xenial_amd64.deb` I downloaded from the virtualbox.org website. (I installed it with on top of the one I installed with `apt` from `deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian xenial contrib`)

My host is running `xenial` and my guest is `Windows 10`

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and in my case it was because I had run out of `inotify` watches.

If this is the case you will see an error when trying to `tail -f` a long file, as suggested in https://askubuntu.com/questions/154255/how-can-i-tell-if-i-am-out-of-inotify-watches. You can then see which processes are consuming inotify watches with `for foo in /proc/*/fd/*; do readlink -f $foo; done | grep inotify | sort | uniq | awk -F'/' '{ print $3}' | xargs ps`, as adapted from [Who's consuming my inotify resources?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15509/whos-consuming-my-inotify-resources).

I eventually discovered this by doing `sudo strace -f VBoxManage list usbhost 2> root.strace` and doing a diff compared to the version running as a normal user.

Answer (score 0):

The error is

```
[pid 21648] access("/dev/vboxusb", R_OK|X_OK) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
```

from my `strace` log.

So i modify the file `/usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxCreateUSBNode.sh` for `/dev/vboxusb` permission.

Then, reboot your pc to solve this issue.